# Obtener el ultimo mensaje con el usuario de un chat PostgreeSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

estoy trabajando en un chat similar al de WhatsApp.
Tengo una base de datos en la cual trate de normalizar todos los campos, pero me veo en la necesidad de hacer un query que obtenga dinámicamente los últimos mensajes.

Tengo 4 tablas para llevar a cabo este flujo:

**Users**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Rooms**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**room_participants**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**messages**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El query que necesito es para obtener los mensajes recientes, junto con el user al que se lo envié, así como los muestra WhatsApp (Un ejemplo)

He intentado unificar mis tablas, para poder obtener mi información, pero no logro obtener solo el ultimo mensaje por cada `room`

```
SELECT * FROM messages m
INNER JOIN rooms r ON r.id = m.room_id
INNER JOIN room_participants rp ON rp.room_id = r.id AND rp.user_id = m.user_id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9ab593/2

Answer (score 0):

Como no incluiste los inserts tuve que hacer algunas peripecias, pero la estrategia básica es la siguiente:

Como los campos de id los definiste como serial son autoincrementales por defecto, de manera que el máximo valor de los índices nos indicará el elemento más reciente.

```
SELECT max(m.id)
  FROM messages m -- el mensaje más reciente
```

y eso sigue funcionando para cuando intersectas dos tablas

```
SELECT max(m.id) -- el mensaje más reciente
  FROM messages m
  INNER JOIN rooms r
    ON r.id = m.room_id -de todos los salones
```

toca hacer subconsultas para sacar el mensaje más reciente de todos y cada uno de los salones de conversación

```
  SELECT max(m.id) -- el mensaje más reciente
  FROM messages m
  INNER JOIN rooms r
    ON r.id = m.room_id
  WHERE r.id=1 -- del primer cuarto
  union  -- agrégale
  SELECT max(m.id) - el mensaje más reciente
  FROM messages m
  INNER JOIN rooms r
    ON r.id = m.room_id
  WHERE r.id=2 -- del segundo cuarto
  .
  .
  .
```

Ahora lo último que toca es seleccionar los campos que quieres mostrar

```
SELECT
      m.id
      , u.username
      , r.name as "Room name"
      , m.message
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN rooms r
  ON r.id = m.room_id
INNER JOIN room_participants rp
  ON rp.room_id = r.id
    AND rp.user_id = m.user_id
INNER JOIN users u
 ON rp.user_id = u.id
WHERE m.id in (
  SELECT max(m.id)
  FROM messages m
  INNER JOIN rooms r
    ON r.id = m.room_id
  WHERE r.id=1
  union
  SELECT max(m.id)
  FROM messages m
  INNER JOIN rooms r
    ON r.id = m.room_id
  WHERE r.id=2
  union
  SELECT max(m.id)
  FROM messages m
  INNER JOIN rooms r
    ON r.id = m.room_id
  WHERE r.id=3
)
-- y así hasta el número de cuartos que quieras mostrar
```

Como verás el tamaño de la consulta crece rápidamente por cada nuevo salón de conversación que agregues a pesar de que cada union te agregue solamente una fila, es por ello que en lo personal considero que el ANSI SQL no es la mejor solución en este caso. Yo me iría directamente a los procedimientos almacenados.

Ahora respecto a cómo le hice para tener datos en la tabla, te lo pongo [en este artículo por si te interesa](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/llenar-base-de-datos-con-datos-de-prueba/).

Obtendrás algo como esto:

[image: resultado de ejecutar la consulta]